# Get undefined result while await recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

Here is my scenario: In my function, I want to wait for another function for doing some recursive thing and return the result in the end. But I just got the undefined result.

Please see find the code in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryan119/6cfp9rqv/14/) here.

My code:

```js
let count = async() => {
  let recursiveFunc = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
    if (index === 0) {
      return "Finish";
    } else {
      index--;
      recursiveFunc(index);
    }
  }
  return recursiveFunc(3);
};

count().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

I expected I will get the log of "3 2 1 0 Finish", but I got "3 2 1 0 undefined".

Please give me some instruction if you find my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: add return to your recursive call: `return recursiveFunc(index);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `return` keyword before `recursiveFunc(index)` call:

```js
let count = async ()=>{

    let recursiveFunc = (index) =>{
      console.log(index);
    if(index === 0){
      return "Finish";
    }else{
      index--;
      return recursiveFunc(index); // <-- here, `return`
    }
  }
    return recursiveFunc(3);
};

count().then(result => {
    console.log(result); 
})
```

You were getting `undefined` in the end because in JavaScript if you don't specify what to return, the function returns `undefined` by default and that's what was happening in your code

Comment: Ah ~ Right! Got it. Thanks for your prompt response!